# How to Remove only Digit with Parentheses () from String in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to remove **Digits** with **Parentheses ()** from string using regex in Python

Example : `Hello World(4353)`

Output: `Hello World`

Example : `Hello World(ABC)`

Output  : `Hello World(ABC)`

I tried this reg but not working Perfectly...

```
s = "Satbaulia Khurd(159ds)"
# pattern=r"([\d ]*(\(\d+\))?[\d ])" 
pattern= r'\([^()]*\)'
res = re.sub(pattern, "", s)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
Satbaulia Khurd
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'\(\d+\)', '', s)`?

Comment: how about `pattern= '\(\d+\)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Quang Hoang in comments `'\(\d+\)'` is a valid regex. That is the code I written based on your examples.

```
import re
string = "Hello World(12345)"
pattern = re.sub(r'\(\d+\)', '', string)
# Hello World(ABC) -> Hello World(ABC)

print(pattern)
```